# How to render a partial view from an action in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an action in a controller that do some operations. I want at the end of these operations to be displayed a modal that is rendered in a partial view. What I do at the end of those operations talked above:

```
return PartialView("_confirmed");
```

But is not displayed anything. The operations are executed but is not displayed the partial view.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Are you returning **PartialViewResult** instead of ActionResult..and what does the html look like

Comment: Your question is not clear.  You need to fully define how you are using the code.

Comment: Right now I've got that the partialview display but it is shown as a new page instead a modal window.

Comment: Why not make an ajax call for the modal?

Comment: You need to show your code!

Answer (score 1):

using `return PartialView("_confirmed");` will return _confirmed view as partial, it means that it won't render the layout from _Layout (or your configured view layout).

Use fiddler or network tab from your browser and check if the html from _confirmed is being returned. If it is being returned, you have a problem in your js that catch the _confirmed html and render it in a model.

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning partial view to the ajax you have to bind the html manually.

### Action

```
public ActionResult Action(...)
{
     var model = ...;    

     return PartialView( "Partial", model.PartialModel ); // in same ControllerI
     return PartialView( "~/Views/ControllerName/ViewName.cshtml, model.PartialModel ); // If its in different controller should mention detailed path
}
```

### If you are using Ajax

```
 $.ajax({
              url: '/controller/action',              
              dataType: 'html',
              success: function(data) {
                 $('#partial').html(data);
              },
              ...
           });
```